# Pentaho: Visibility of levels from shared dimension across multiple cubes

Tags: pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian

I have 1 shared dimension named 'Customer' which I am using across multiple cubes. I have five columns ID,Name,Age,Description,Work in the shared dimension Customer under one hierarchy. Now, I have to display ID and Name in attribute in 'A' cube. And ID and Age attribute in other cube 'B' (Both the cubes are in same schema). This is just an example. I have many columns in shared dimension which I cannot keep on repeating in separate cubes.